# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (contact_number, address, user_type) specified for User

Tags: django

**how to solve this error:**

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (contact_number, address, user_type) specified for User.
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['first_name','last_name','address','contact_number','user_type','username','password']
        widgets = {'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
            'address': forms.Textarea(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
            'contact_number': forms.IntegerField(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
            'user_type': forms.Select(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }), 
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' })
      }
```

I am getting difficulty here please tell me what to do.

Comment: Django's user model doesn't have any fields called `contact_number`, `address` and `user_type`, hence the error. Where are you expecting those fields to be defined? If you are using a custom user model, then you need to follow Django's [instructions for setting that up](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: so i cannot add extra fields there?

Comment: Additional fields need to be defined outside the `Meta class`. If your need is to add additional fields to the `User`  model you need to do that first

Comment: please tell me how to do this

Comment: [How to extend Django User model?](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) a beginner-friendly tutorial. Refer to the doc for in-depth understanding.

Comment: I asked this question 5 months ago and now i am getting negative vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's inbuilt User model don't have fields like `address` , `user_type` , `contact_number`

Therefore you can create a custom model named as `profile` or something else:

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Class Profile(models.Model):
    parent=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Now you can co relate your view to this

This is simply a way of extending the User model in django.
There are also different ways on django's official website.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user